# RC differentiator giving a higher output amplitude than input amplitude

Tags: high-pass-filter

This is the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9W39N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And this is the output:

[image: output]

I am unable to understand the increase in output amplitude as compared to the input's amplitude. Mathematically it makes sense - rate of change is quite high. But electronically I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it. How can additional voltage be generated with R and C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of a capacitor as "liking to keep the voltage across it constant" - at least in the short term.

[image]

*Figure 1. Voltage difference analysis.*

Just prior to the squarewave step down at (1) we can see that the right hand side of C1 is at 0 V so there is -1 V across the capacitor. Immediately after the step down there is still -1 V across the capacitor. Because the left side jumped from +1 to -1 the right side is "kicked" from 0 to -2 V.

We get a similar but opposite effect at (2).

In both cases capacitor voltage is maintained at 2 V for the instant of the square transition and is followed by the RC discharge.

Comment: Crystal clear now. :)

Comment: Good. You can similarly think of inductors as "liking to keep the current through them constant" (again in the short term).

Answer (score 6):

It's called "charge pumping", and it is sometimes used to create low-power boosted-voltage supplies for some applications.

At the end of each half-cycle, the capacitor is essentially charged to the same voltage as the source. When the next half-cycle starts, this voltage cannot change instantaneously, so the capacitor voltage is added (in series) to the source voltage. But this quickly discharges through the resistor, and by the end of that half-cycle, the capacitor is charged in the other direction.